# Common footer for all web pages

Tags: html, css, footer

I have a website where I need to have a common footer for all the pages. However the pages content varies and few pages have less body and few have scrollable body. But my footer doesn't stay the same for all the pages. I need it to be at the bottom for all the pages (after the body). I tried multiple ways using CSS, javascript, jquery but they work only for one page and not all together.

Could someone help me with this.

Comment: After the body? why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

Comment: Server side includes perhaps?

Comment: your markup which is expected to be shown in the browser should be inside the `body` tag.

Comment: I have few grids in the body and I need the footer after all the grids.

Comment: After the body, or </body>?

Comment: Do you want it on the bottom everywhere, or the same everywhere, or something else? Please clarify.

Comment: @Sri if you want the same footer everywhere, create a php footer and include it your files. If your files are currently .html, the easiest way to make this work would be to rename them to .php but there are other ways

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with this as well! I have learned that the key is to have a wrapper id:

**html:**

```
<html>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">


<div class="content">

<p> This is the content! </p>

</div> <!-- content -->



<footer>

<p> This is the footer!!! </p>

</footer>

<div> <!--#wrapper-->

</body>

</html>
```

**css:**

```
html {
height:100%;
}


body {
height:100%; 
}

#wrapper{
min-height:100%;
position: relative;
}

footer{
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
background-color: black;
color: white;
width:100%;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-bottom: 25px;
text-align:center;

}
```

Comment: @Sri pls don't use this answer!